# Redis is storing "null" string when used for session management. How to fix the error?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, redis

We are using redis server for tomcat session persistence. All the tomcat session are stored in redis session. Tomcat session manager we are using is: https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager

Sometimes in redis "null" values are getting stored and hence when I load the homepage or any page, tomcat throw exception saying

> "Race condition encountered: attempted to load session[SESSION_ID]
>   which has been created but not yet serialized."

In this case how can I destroy the session properly? Because I don't have control anywhere inside any servlet or filter. Please have a look at this exception from tomcat[image: Tomcat giving error]